# Definition of a socket

Tags: ip, tcp, networking, transport-protocol

I wanted to confirm whether the definition of a socket I've understood in a computer network context is true.

A socket is file who is unique and named by local IP,Local port, Foreign IP and foreign Port.

When the transport layer receives the data for a particular port, it puts that data into the respective socket file and then the application can read from the file accordingly. This is also known as demultiplexing.

In the reverse case,when the application layer wants to send data to transport layer, it puts the data into a respective socket and then the transport protocol reads from it,creating segments.This is known as multiplexing.

Comment: A socket is not a file - but some structure with associated buffers, states ... And a socket is not restricted to IP, port etc but there are a many kind of sockets (UDP, TCP, Raw, UNIX, netlink, ...).

Comment: Okay..
Can you tell me why UDP sockets use only destination IP address and destination port number whereas TCP sockets use source IP address,source port number,destination IP address and destination port number.

Comment: I cannot tell you why this is the case because it isn't the case. Both TCP and UDP sockets can be connected or not - and only connected sockets have peer information. One can use unconnected UDP sockets for sending to arbitrary targets, while for data transfer in TCP one needs a connected socket since TCP requires established connections with associated states to achieve the reliability requirements. Unconnected TCP sockets are used for listening and accepting new connections instead.